# paypal REST .net api extract VALIDATION_ERROR

Tags: .net, api, rest, paypal

Is there anyway to extract any validation errors after attempting to create a payment with a credit card?  In the log I see errors like this but it would be nice to be able to report back to the user what is wrong with the data they have typed into the check out fields.

```
{"name":"VALIDATION_ERROR","details":[{"field":"payer.funding_instruments[0].credit_card.billing_address.line2","issue":"Must contain only these characters: a-z, A-Z, 0-9, punctuation(.,#-'), and embedded spaces"}],"message":"Invalid request - see details","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#VALIDATION_ERROR","debug_id":"b5f35e3567798"}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using V0.7.1 or upwards of the SDK, you can retrieve the response payload for non-200 responses by

- Catching the thrown PayPalException, and
- Reading the Response property of the InnerException (in this case, ConnectionException)

The Response property returns only the raw server response as a string. You may want to decode the json string in to an object.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have been able to extract the string with vb.net... sErrorResponse = DirectCast(ex.InnerException, PayPal.Exception.ConnectionException).Response   But I don't much about JSON, do you have to create a data structure for this error string before converting into an object?